# Adding similar lines in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with below records:

```
$ cat sample.txt
ABC,100
XYZ,50
ABC,150
QWE,100
ABC,50
XYZ,100
```

Expecting the output to be:

```
$ cat output.txt
ABC,300
XYZ,150
QWE,100
```

I tried the below script:

```
PREVVAL1=0
SUM1=0
cat sam.txt | sort >  /tmp/Pos.part
while read line
do
VAL1=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
VAL2=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}')
if [ $VAL1 == $PREVVAL1 ]
then
SUM1=` expr $SUM + $VAL2`
PREVVAL1=$VAL1
echo $VAL1 $SUM1
else
SUM1=$VAL2
PREVVAL1=$VAL1
fi
done < /tmp/Pos.part
```

I want to get some one liner command to get the required output. Wanted to avoid the while loop concept. I want to just add the numbers where the first column is same and show it in a single line.

Comment: It would be easy using `awk`, just accumulate in an associative array.

Comment: You don't need to use `awk` to split the line on comma. Use `while IFS=, read VAL1 VAL2`

Comment: I need to get out of while loop and just get some one liner command for the same. Is it possible?

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. There's no reason for `expr` in modern code, and running a pipeline starting a new copy of `awk` for every single line you process is *insanely* inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$2} END{for (i in a) print i FS a[i]}' sample.txt
```

Output

```
QWE,100
XYZ,150
ABC,300
```

The first part is executed for each line and creates an associative array. The `END` part prints this array.

Comment: One issue I found is, if the value is large the result comes in exponential format with above command @steffen

Comment: @Programmer Use gawk instead of awk. If that's still not enough and you have extremely big integers, use `gawk -M` or `gawk --bignum`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (key in sum) print key, sum[key]}' sample.txt > output.txt
```

`sum[$1] += $2` creates an associative array whose keys are the first field and values are the corresponding sums.

Comment: Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done easily enough in native bash. The following uses no external tools, no subshells and no pipelines, and is thus *far* faster (I'd place money on 100x the throughput on a typical/reasonable system) than your original code:

```
declare -A sums=( )
while IFS=, read -r name val; do
  sums[$name]=$(( ${sums[$name]:-0} + val ))
done

for key in "${!sums[@]}"; do
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$key" "${sums[$key]}"
done
```

If you want to, you can make this a one-liner:

```
declare -A sums=( ); while IFS=, read -r name val; do sums[$name]=$(( ${sums[$name]:-0} + val )); done; for key in "${!sums[@]}"; do printf '%s,%s\n' "$key" "${sums[$key]}"; done
```